# XUnit Test DbContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, xunit

How can I pass the DBContext when initializing in `CustomWebApplicationFactory` to make tests in the xUnit file or correct the error ?

```
public class CustomWebApplicationFactory : WebApplicationFactory<quest_web.Startup>
{
        public APIDbContext Context;
        protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(ConfigureServices)
            .UseEnvironment("Development");
        }
        private void ConfigureServices(WebHostBuilderContext webHostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            var dbContextService = serviceCollection.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<APIDbContext>));
            if(dbContextService != null)
            {
                serviceCollection.Remove(dbContextService);
            }

            var provider = serviceCollection
                    .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
                    .BuildServiceProvider();
            serviceCollection.AddDbContext<APIDbContext>(contextOptions => {
                contextOptions.UseInMemoryDatabase("quest_web");
                contextOptions.UseInternalServiceProvider(provider);
            });

            var sp = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            using (var scope = sp.CreateScope())
            {
                var scopedServices = scope.ServiceProvider;
                Context = scopedServices.GetRequiredService<APIDbContext>();   
                Context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                Context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            }
            
        }
}
```

When calling the test the context returns the error

```
public class Test
    {
        private readonly APIDbContext _context;
        private readonly HttpClient _client;
        public Test()
        {
            factory = new CustomWebApplicationFactory();
            _client = factory.CreateClient();
            _context = factory.Context;
        }
        [Fact]
        private async void Test_dbcontext()
        {
            User user = new User("username", "password");
            _context.User.Add(user);
            _context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

There is my feeback error

> System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.

[UPDATE]
Use Singleton and not scoped lifetime

Comment: Where is `factory` declared and what is its scope? I think your code as given will have a compilation error since there is no declaration. If `factory` goes out of scope in the constructor, maybe it also disposes its `Context` and leads to your problem.

Comment: Or in the `using (var scope ...` the `scope` disposes the Context when it itself is disposed.